# Unit testing NodeJS stream with jest - timeout issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, jestjs, node-streams

Given the following NodeJS Transform Stream:

```
class ObjectToCSVTransform extends Transform {
  private hasSetHeaders: boolean;

  constructor() {
    super({ objectMode: true });
    this.hasSetHeaders = false;
  }

  static create(): ObjectToCSVTransform {
    return new this();
  }

  _write(
    object: Record<string, unkwnown>,
    _encoding: BufferEncoding,
    callback: TransformCallback
  ): void {
    this.push(this.generateCSV(telemetry));
    callback();
  }

  private generateCSV(object: Record<string, unkwnown>): string {
    let csv = '';

    if (!this.hasSetHeaders) {
      csv += this.createCSVHeaders(object);
      this.hasSetHeaders = true;
    }

    csv += this.createRecord(object);

    return csv;
  }

  private createCSVHeaders(object: Record<string, unkwnown>): string {
    return `${Object.keys(object)}\n`;
  }

  private createCSVRecord(object: Record<string, unkwnown>): string {
    return `${Object.values(object)}\n`;
  }
}
```

I implemented the following test case (using **jest**), to test that given a stream of plain objects of the *"same type"* the expected output is a valid CSV representation of them:

```
describe('object to csv stream', () => {
  const items: Record<string, unknown> = [
    { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 },
    { foo: 10, bar: 20, baz: 30 },
    { foo: 100, bar: 200, baz: 300 },
  ];

  it('should transform a list of items to csv', (done) => {
    const expectedCsv = 'foo,bar,baz\n1,2,3\n10,20,30\n100,200,300\n';
    let csv = '';

    Readable.from(items)
      .pipe(ObjectToCSVTransform.create())
      .on('data', (csvResult) => {
        csv += csvResult;
        console.log(csvResult); // just for debugging purposes
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('streaming ended'); // just for debugging purposes
        expect(csv).toEqual(expectedCsv);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```

Apparently, **during the test case implementation I wanted to see how my test case failed**: the stream seemed to work as it logged every expected csv result line and the `'streaming ended'` message also at the end once the stream ended, but the test execution did not finish at all then. It was jest that actually finished the execution after exceeding the default timeout:

> thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test. Use
> jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is
> a long-running test."

What am I missing here?

*Note that I am currently using the jest callback to notify when the async operation has finished.*

Comment: The reason is likely that the transform is still open. You need to implement _transform() for all custom transform classes.

Comment: @kevintechie do you know how implementing the `_transform()` will affect on the stream closing?

Comment: The underlying scream needs the callback() to be called so that it knows when processing of each chunk is done.

Comment: If you just replace _write with _transform() this will probably work. Using _write may be just monkey-patching the internal _write implementation.

Comment: Ha. Just noticed the typo in my previous comment. Scream should be stream.

Comment: There are several problems with the above code that prevent it from running. Can you fix you code, make sure your example executes and demonstrates your problem, and then update your example code?

Comment: My previous comments about the name of the transform function are not correct. However, by convention, this function is named _transform().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is something that I was missing in my test case that wasn't handling asynchrony correctly at all and therefore was making the `Exceeded timeout exception` to be thrown by jest:

- surrounding the assertion by a try-catch and having the `done()` callback called in case the assertion failed.

```
.on('end', () => {
  try {
    expect(csv).toEqual(expectedCsv);
    done();
  } catch (error) {
    done(error);
  }
});
```

For more info / reference, check the jest docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#callbacks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the returned value of `csv` is not matching the expected value. The actual returned value includes a `\n` at the end. If you add this to your `expectedCsv` string, your test will pass.

The timeout error is a red herring.

If you `console.log(csv.replace(/\n/g, '\\n'))` in the 'end' function you will see the extra linefeed at the end of the string.

```
import { Readable, Transform, TransformCallback } from 'stream';

class ObjectToCSVTransform extends Transform {
  private hasSetHeaders: boolean;

  constructor() {
    super({ objectMode: true });
    this.hasSetHeaders = false;
  }

  static create(): ObjectToCSVTransform {
    return new this();
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line no-underscore-dangle
  _write(
    object: Record<string, unknown>,
    _encoding: 'utf8',
    callback: TransformCallback,
  ): void {
    this.push(this.generateCSV(object));
    callback();
  }

  private generateCSV(object: Record<string, unknown>): string {
    let csv = '';

    if (!this.hasSetHeaders) {
      csv += this.createCSVHeaders(object);
      this.hasSetHeaders = true;
    }

    csv += this.createCSVRecord(object);

    return csv;
  }

  private createCSVHeaders(object: Record<string, unknown>): string {
    return `${Object.keys(object)}\n`;
  }

  private createCSVRecord(object: Record<string, unknown>): string {
    return `${Object.values(object)}\n`;
  }
}

describe('object to csv stream', () => {
  const items: Record<string, unknown>[] = [
    { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 },
    { foo: 10, bar: 20, baz: 30 },
    { foo: 100, bar: 200, baz: 300 },
  ];

  it('should transform a list of items to csv', (done) => {
    const expectedCsv = 'foo,bar,baz\n1,2,3\n10,20,30\n100,200,300\n';
    let csv = '';

    Readable.from(items)
      .pipe(ObjectToCSVTransform.create())
      .on('data', (csvResult) => {
        csv += csvResult;
        console.log(csvResult); // just for debugging purposes
      })
      .on('end', () => {
        console.log('streaming ended'); // just for debugging purposes
        console.log(csv.replace(/\n/g, '\\n'));
        expect(csv).toEqual(expectedCsv);
        done();
      });
  });
});
```